# Checking whether or not a UITableView cell contains a keyword

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uitableview, nsstring, nsrange

I was trying to see if a `UITableView` cell contains a string.

I have tried using:

```
if ([cell.textlabel.text rangeOfString:@"Ok"].location !=NSNotFound) 
{
}
```

But that was no use. It found the text every time no matter what.

Answer (score 1):

You should test if the `cell.textlabel.text` string is not `nil`. I've tested your code with a `nil` value and always returns `TRUE`.

```
if(cell.textlabel.text)
{
    if ([cell.textlabel.text rangeOfString:@"Ok"].location !=NSNotFound) 
    {
        ...
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this below:-

```
NSString *str=cell.textlabel.text;
if ([str rangeOfString:@"Ok"].location !=NSNotFound) 
{
}
```